# Spring Batch to read from a csv file and use its data in Select query as well as insert query

Tags: java, spring

I have a task to write a program using spring where I read data from a csv file and use the data to query SQL using select statement.

For now I have been able to read through the file and return the list but I'm not getting any further.

I am very much new to spring.

Can someone help?

```java
@Configuration
public class ItemHandler {

        private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItemHandler.class);

        @Bean
        public ItemReader<List<String>> jdbcCursorItemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
                JdbcCursorItemReader<List<String>> cursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<List<String>>();

                cursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
                cursorItemReader.setIgnoreWarnings(true);

                cursorItemReader.setRowMapper((r, i) -> {
                        return Arrays.asList(r.getString(1), r.getString(2), r.getString(3), r.getString(4));
                });

                cursorItemReader.setSql("SQL");

                return cursorItemReader;
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemProcessor<List<String>, List<String>> nonProcessingItemProcessor() {
                return (item->item);
        }
}
```

This is my Item reader and Processor which is getting 4 columns from SQL.

I need and item writer with a select statement inside and insert statement where the select statement is provided with values dynamically from item reader

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i have updated my question